# How to Modify a String in wx.StaticText?

Tags: python, string, wxpython, static-text

I have a tuple: ('a',1)

When I use wx.StaticText to show it, it is always displayed like this: ('a',1)

How do I make it display like this: (a,1) ?

Note: It has to be a tuple. For some reason when I set a string to be a tuple it is always recorded along with the quotes. So:

```
a = (str(hello),1)
```

And if you print a you get:

```
>>>print a
('hello',1)
```

Comment: It would also be nice if I could get rid of the brackets too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing the tuple object directly, pass a string formatted:

```
>>> a = ('a', 1)
```

Using [`%` operator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations):

```
>>> '(%s, %s)' % a
'(a, 1)'

>>> '%s, %s' % a  # without parentheses
'a, 1'
```

Using [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
>>> '({0[0]}, {0[1]})'.format(a)
'(a, 1)'
>>> '({}, {})'.format(*a)
'(a, 1)'

>>> '{0[0]}, {0[1]}'.format(a)   # without parentheses
'a, 1'
>>> '{}, {}'.format(*a)          # without parentheses
'a, 1'
```

Comment: Is there a way to remove those quotes at the very last part (# without parentheses) ?

Comment: @YelloFour, `'` is there to let user know that the object is string object. `'` is not included in the string itself. Try to print it, then you will know what I mean: `print('{}, {}'.format(*a))` or `print('%s, %s' % a)`

Comment: Yes that's the problem for my case because it seems that python has some sort of functionality in its print that removes those quotes but when you put it inside of wx.StaticText it does not have that same functionality as print so the quotes remain.

Comment: Never mind I just tried it and it works. Thank a lot for your help :)

Comment: How would you do this same thing but if you had "('A',1)" instead? I can't get it to work :(

Comment: @YelloFour, `"('a', 1)".strip('()').replace("'", '')`. But it will remove `'` unexpectedly if there's `'` in the string content. Why don't you use the method given in the answer?

Comment: I can't use it because now I am trying to turn a list like this:        [['A',1].['B',2]] into (A,1) (B,2). The double brackets are being hard to deal with.

Comment: @YelloFour, `' '.join('(%s, %s)' % (s, n) for s, n in [['A',1],['B',2]])`